# Javascript object Map, how to get key from value if multiple keys map to same value

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm not sure if understand JavaScript Object Maps correctly and can't figure out if something is an error or if that's how it is.

In code below I can understand first 3 console messages.

*But should the last console.log - show nothing?*

```
let key1 = 3;
let key2 = 6;
let key3 = 14;
let myMap= new Map();

myMap.set(key1, 'Buy');
myMap.set(key2, 'Buy');
myMap.set(key3, 'Sell');

console.log(myMap.get(key1));   // Buy
console.log(myMap.get(key2));   //Buy 
console.log(myMap.get(key3));   //Sell
console.log(myMap.get('Buy'));   //.....nothing
```

**The MDN page says: "Any value (both objects and primitive values) may be used as either a key or a value."** 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

So, from what I understand, 'Buy' which is a value, should map to both key1 & key2.

Can someone confirm the reason for this behavior? Thanks

Comment: The `myMap.get()` expects a key not a value. When you look for the key "Buy" is going to return nothing because that key does not exist in that Map. Maybe what they are trying to tell you is that map values dont need to be unique wile key are.

Answer (score 2):

No, what they mean is that you can use any object as a key in the map, and you can store any object as a value in the map. It doesn't mean that values are also keys. That would be a weird, unexpected, and unwanted behavior.

Comment: ahh, that explains. I was trying to get a data structure which is internally implemented as a cross product of keys and values.